# Change height of li when ancestor has class CSS (LESS)

Tags: html, css, less

I have an HTML menu with a structure similar to this:

```
<div class="main-menu">
    <div class="block">
       <ul>
           <li class="title">TITLE</li>
           <li class="option">OPTION</li>
           <li class="option">OPTION</li>
           <li class="option">OPTION</li>
           <li class="option">OPTION</li>
       </ul> 
   </div>
   <div class="block">
       <ul>
           <li class="title">TITLE</li>
           <li class="option">OPTION</li>
           <li class="option">OPTION</li>
           <li class="option">OPTION</li>
           <li class="option">OPTION</li>
           <li class="option">OPTION</li>
           <li class="option">OPTION</li>
       </ul> 
   </div>
     .
     .
     .
</div>
```

The appearance is the following:

[image: Menu on normal state]

The tricky part comes when i have to display the block with more options (the default is 4), for that i created a class that changes the height of the menu so it can fit all the options, like this:

[image: ![Menu with 'tall' class]

I would like to make the space beneath the last title also gray without changing the html (it must respect that structure so the javascript behind it can work like it does with similar components); I tought of changing the height of the last title when the main menu has the 'tall' class, but i can't reach that li (I'm using less) to do so. Here's what I've done in the partial that contains the styles  (I added comments on the more important lines):

```
.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}

.card-ops-panel { // This is the main-menu
    width: 600px;
    height: 320px;
    background-color: @white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2.5rem;
    z-index: 100;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 0 rgba(97, 112, 119, 0.15), 10px 0px 20px 0 rgba(97, 112, 119, 0.15);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 0 rgba(97, 112, 119, 0.15), 10px 0px 20px 0 rgba(97, 112, 119, 0.15);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 0 rgba(97, 112, 119, 0.15), 10px 0px 20px 0 rgba(97, 112, 119, 0.15);
    transition: all .6s;
    &.first {
        left: 0;
    }
    &.second {
        right: -537%;
    }
    &.third {
        right: -373%;
    }
    &.fourth {
        right: -125%;
    }
    &.panel-2-col {
        width: 900px;
        &.second {
            right: -625%;
        }
    }
    &.panel--tall { //Class that makes the menu fit more than 4 options
        height: 560px;
    }
    &__block {
        .block {
            .block__title {
                padding: 30px 24px;
                width: 300px;
                height: 80px;
                position: absolute;
                float: left;
                background-color: @gray-white;
                &.block__title--active {
                    background-color: #ffffff;
                    color: @brand-primary;
                }
                &__icon {
                    margin-right: 10px;
                    line-height: .7;
                }
                &__text {
                    line-height: 0.7;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 2.1rem;
                }
            }
            .block__option {
                background-color: #ffffff;
                width: 300px;
                height: 80px;
                padding: 30px 24px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 300px;
                .block__option__link {
                    &:focus {
                        color: @white;
                        background-color: @gray-dark;
                    }
                }
                &:nth-child(3) {
                    top: 80px;
                }
                &:nth-child(4) {
                    top: 160px;
                }
                &:nth-child(5) {
                    top: 240px;
                }
                &:nth-child(6) {
                    top: 320px;
                }
                &:nth-child(7) {
                    top: 400px;
                }
                &:nth-child(8) {
                    top: 480px;
                }
            }
            &.block-2-col {
                column-count: 2;
                column-width: 300px;
                column-gap: 0;
            }
        }
        &:nth-child(2) { // section of the menu
            .block {
                .block__title {
                    top: 5rem;
                }
            }
        }
        &:nth-child(3) { // section of the menu
            .block {
                .block__title {
                    top: 10rem;
                }
            }
        }
        &:nth-child(4) { // section of the menu
            .block {
                .block__title { //Last title (the one I want to make bigger when the main-menu has the 'panel--tall' class
                    top: 15rem;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can add more height to the last title when the main menu has the 'panel--tall' class? If it isn't possible, any suggestions of how can i make the space beneath the same color?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style the last element differently depending on the `.panel-tall` class on the `.cards-ops-panel`, you can use a selector like this:

```
.card-ops-panel {
    &.panel--tall &__block:nth-child(4) {
        .block {
            .block__title {
                // Styles here...
            }
        }
    }
}
```